# Set Font to Fit Defined Width PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I'm new to using PHP's GD library and I'd like to be able to resize (shrink/enlarge) my text to fit a certain width.

As an example, say I have a string, "Hello World".  What is the easiest way to have this string resize itself to fit within a defined area (say 200px x 100px)?  The size of the area for this text can change, so it would need to be dynamic and change the fontsize accordingly.

Not sure if I'm explaining this very well - but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Font Size For Text (GD via PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289850/auto-font-size-for-text-gd-via-php)